# how to check if node server compressed the file at client end

Tags: node.js, gzip

I m learning the nodejs, and I used the gzip to compress the requested file, but I don't know how to show the compressed size at the client end. I know the Chrome dev tool shows the size of the compressed file. Is there any way to show the compressed size at client page

Comment: If you look at a resource in the `Network` tab in `Chrome` and see `content-encoding: gzip` in `Response Headers` that'd indicate whether the requested file was compressed.

Comment: yes, I can check that manually, but how to demonstrate it on the client page? more specifically, how to get the package size transferred over the network?

Comment: not sure what you mean? Like this? `<p>compressed size: {size}</p>`, or something similar?

Comment: yea, something like this, but I don't know how to get the compressed size since the browser has decompressed the response.
I can get the actual size of file use the response.length
but I m trying to get the size before decompressed

Comment: Like this? https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4607/is-there-an-easy-way-to-see-amount-of-compression-in-chrome